# Arbitrary depth slash-delimited param value in Ember route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a route defined as:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('folder', { path: '/f/:path' }, function() {} );
});
```

And the route itself as:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    const path = params.path;
    console.log(`path=${ path }`);
    return path;
  }
});
```

Currently:

```
http://localhost:4200/f/folder
```

works but

```
http://localhost:4200/f/folder/subfolder
```

throws a `Uncaught UnrecognizedURLError {message: "/f/folder/subfolder", name: "UnrecognizedURLError"}` since the router is expecting me to define a route at each level.

Use case is the ability for users to build an arbitrary tree of folders. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have read one more paragraph here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/defining-your-routes/

What I'm looking for is a wildcard / globbing route.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('folder', { path: '/f/*path' });
});
```

Gives me the output I was hoping for:

```
path=folder/subfolder
```